# facebook registration not showing up

Tags: jquery, facebook

I'm checking to see if a user has registered my app and if not I'm trying to show a facebook registration button but it's not showing up.

Here is the javascript code that I have in the footer of my webpage:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId   : '281914178557709',
      status  : true, // check login status
      cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
      } 
      else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        alert("Show registration");
        $('#fb_register').html('<label class="control-label" for="fname">&nbsp;</label><div class="controls"><fb:login-button registration-url="/register_facebook.php" /></div>');
      }
   });             
};

(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script');
  e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  e.async = true;
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

My div tag is simply this:

```
<div class="control-group" id="fb_register"></div>
```

I see my alert message so I know I'm hitting the correct area but the button fails to render.  If I use straight text it renders.  Any idea why the XFBML isn't being rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the xfbml is being parsed prior to the insertion of the facebook login button, the best method would be to wrap the facebook login button in a div and set its display to none, then toggle it's display to block if the user is authenticated.

Comment: This would only work if they've signed into their facebook account correct?